# UI Router erroring out

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to test out UI Router with an existing app.  Of course I'm running into issues early on.  Here is what i have so far:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('hon.configurator.uiroutes', ['ui.router', 'ncy-angular-breadcrumb']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$stateParams', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                }
            })
            .state('series', {
                url: '/:series',
                controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                }
            })
            .state('configurator', {
                url: '/:series/:configurator'
            });
    }]);

})();
```

I'm getting an error with [$injector:unpr] $stateParams.

This does get minified, which I know can be an issue, but I'm sure if that's an issue here, and if it is, how to fix it with the controller: syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `$stateParams` inside the configuration, because only providers & constant are accessible inside the angular config phase and $stateParams is the `value` service.

```
angular.module('ui.router.state')
  .value('$stateParams', {});
```

Basically you need to remove `$stateParams` dependency from config function

Change

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$stateParams', function ($stateProvider) {
```

to

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
```

Comment: @spuppett Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: I'm getting the error, but It also doesn't look like the routes are getting hit.  There are no logs getting written to the console.  The url looks like:  Configurator/Pages/app.aspx#/thing1/config1.  I wonder if the URLs are wrong or if it just doesn't do what I think it does.  I imagined that when it (the stateProvider) saw these URLs, it would 'trigger' that state.  I injected this module in my boot module, thinking it would cover my whole app and all the controllers, but maybe not?